# JSP doesn't receive own variables

Tags: java, forms, jsp

i have in resume this code, my JSP name is ComEtiquetado on my html form i use action="ComEtiquetado.jsp" but i cant get the variable

```
cd = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cd").toString());
```

it gets a null message on catch

```
int cd=-1
try{
    cd =     Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cd").toString());
    if (cd>-1){
        con.query("Update Calendario set consecutivo='"+cd+"' where medio  like '%cd%' ");
    }
}
catch(Exception exception2){}
<form id="con" name="con" method="post" action="ComEtiquetado.jsp">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        El consecutivo
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Cd esta en <font color="red"><%=Ccd %> </font> Cambiar a : 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cd" name="cd" size="3"> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Cambiar" >
      </td>
  </table>  
</form>
```

the weird thing is that i have the exact same code on other page and it works fine there

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
int cd=-1;

string myValue = request.getParameter("cd");

if(myValue != null && myValue != ""){

try{

    cd =     Integer.parseInt(myValue);

    if (cd>-1){
                con.query("Update Calendario set consecutivo='"+cd+"' where medio  like '%cd%' ");
            }      

 }
 catch(Exception ex){

}

}
```